# Keras/Tensorflow - fourier pointwise multiplication implementation of conv2d running 4x slower than spatial convolution

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, fft, conv-neural-network

According to the convolution theorem, convolution changes to pointwise multiplication in the fourier domain, and the overheads of taking the fourier transform have been shown to be overshadowed by the gain due to conversion of convolution operation to pointwise multiplication operation in many previous works like the following - [https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5851.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.5851)

To replicate this, I was trying to replace the keras.layers.Conv2D() layer by a custom layer that accepts the rfft of input data (I took the rfft of data before feeding it into the model to reduce training time), initialises 'no_of_kernels' number of kernels of the same size as the image, takes its rfft, multiplies the input and kernel pointwise and returns the product (yes, without taking irfft since I want to further train the network in fourier domain itself) -

In the layer, the call function is implemented as follows -
Note - in my dataset, i.e. MNIST image height = width, so the transpose works fine

```
def call(self, x):
        fft_x = x #(batch_size, height, width, in_channels)
        fft_kernel = tf.spectral.rfft2d(self.kernel) #(in_channels, height, width, out_channels)
        fft_kernel = tf.transpose(fft_kernel, perm=[2, 1, 0, 3]) #(width, height, in_channels, out_channels)
        output  = tf.einsum('ijkl,jklo->ijko', fft_x, fft_kernel)
        return output
```

This code preserves accuracy given by Keras Conv2D layer, but it runs around 4 times slower than Conv2D, thus the purpose of transforming into fourier domain is defeated. Could anyone please clarify why this happens and how can I replicate the results of fast convolutions in the fourier domain?

(Note - For anyone who might feel tf.spectral.rfft2d(self.kernel) might be the overhead, it is not the case as I have verified.

Also, I think the Conv2D function might be flattening the 4D input tensors and kernels to reduce it to matrix multiplication as explained here - [enter link description here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d). I could not think of any intelligent method of flattening etc. to perform pointwise multiplication except for viewing it as dot product as I have done with tf.einsum. Is there any intelligent method to do pointwise multiplication? )
Thanks.

Edit - 
Entire implementation of the layer for reference-

```
class Fourier_Conv2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, no_of_kernels, **kwargs):
        self.no_of_kernels = no_of_kernels
        super(Fourier_Conv2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel_shape = (int(input_shape[3]), int(input_shape[1]), int(input_shape[2]), self.no_of_kernels)
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(name = 'kernel', 
                                      shape = self.kernel_shape, 
                                      initializer = 'uniform', trainable = True)
        super(Fourier_Conv2D, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        fft_x = x
        fft_kernel = tf.spectral.rfft2d(self.kernel)
        fft_kernel = tf.transpose(fft_kernel, perm=[2, 1, 0, 3])
        output  = tf.einsum('ijkl,jklo->ijko', fft_x, fft_kernel)
        return output       

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2], int(self.no_of_kernels/2)+1)
```

Comment: In the Conv2D layer, I had used a 3x3 kernel. In the fourier_conv2D I initialise a kernel of the same size as the image. Since this increases the number of learnable parameters, I also tried initialising a 3x3 kernel and padding it to the image size before taking fft. But that is also as slow as the former, indicating that the bottleneck is not in the learning phase of the kernel but in the pointwise multiplication part. Also I see the fourier_conv2d may give significant speedup over conv2d only in case of large kernels, but it should atleast run in time comparable to conv2d and not this slow.

Comment: "it should atleast run in time comparable to conv2d" Why? conv2d does 3x3=9 multiplications and additions (MADs) per pixel. One FFT requires a whole lot more than that. And you need to do 2 FFTs, and then still multiply the two results. Note that the 9 MADs take less time on a modern CPU than getting the image data from RAM to the CPU and writing the result back to RAM. With the FFT route you have a lot more data, even if you compute only half the frequency domain, because your kernel now becomes as much data as the image itself. And you need to iterate over your image twice, not just once.

Comment: Also, in the abstract of the paper you linked, it says "while reusing the same transformed feature map many times". That is, they compute the FFT of all input images, and then train their network on the transformed data. They are taking the cost of the FFT out of the equation. Now they go from 9 MADs per pixel to 1 multiplication per pixel. I'd have to read the paper to understand what they do with the kernel weights, it seems that they would have many more of those.

Comment: By iterating over image twice, do you mean once for fft and once for pointwise multiplication? Regarding the fft of the images/input data, I have taken the fft of entire dataset before starting training, so that time doesn't count here. And wrt the fft of the kernel, I had also tried with initialising a complex64 kernel directly rather than initialising real kernel and then taking fft so this overhead was also removed. But still it ran as slow as this case. So it made me feel the overhead is really in the pointwise multiplication part, which is also multiplication of complex numbers

Comment: Did you try removing the transpose? You should be able to use `einsum` without it: `ijkl,ljko->ijko`. Though it is likely that `tf.einsum` is just slow.

Comment: Ok, I just tried that but it is just a little faster than that with transpose. Like - it takes less that 5 minutes per epoch using conv_2d and anywhere between 30-50 minutes per epoch using fourier_conv2d (for all versions inculding with/without transpose, with/without fft of kernel etc.)

Comment: I thought tf.spectral.rfft2d works on the "innermost two dimensions", i.e. height and width, that is why I initialised that way and took transpose after this function. Yes, the accuracy is preserved as in conv2d.

Comment: I don't know tensorflow. I assumed the innermost two dimensions would be the first two.

Comment: I know this question is very old, but for anyone looking through comments, the paper linked compares the theoretical flops of a standard convolution algorithm and the fft approach. In practice, on GPUs, they can use algorithms that heavily leverage the large memory available to reduce the latency. i.e. use Winograd, GEMM etc. Therefore, use more FLOPs, but in practice lower latency. FFT approaches are generally only practically faster when you use much larger kernel dimensions 5x5 + whereby Winograd is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your result is surprising at all, the implementation of Conv2D in Keras is left to the backend, and most backends (like TensorFlow) have very optimized versions of the convolution operations, specially if you use CuDNN. So your own version, which should be faster than a naive implementation, is slower than a highly optimized one.

Its possible that in order to make a meaningful comparison, you will have to implement a baseline Conv2D that does convolution in a naive way, without any kind of optimizations.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I will try to implement a base conv2D spatial implementation and then compare. But I am not using CuDNN, so both codes are running on CPU. Does the  Tensorflow backend optimise on CPU as well?

Comment: Yes, it should also be optimized, possibly using im2col and BLAS.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I read Tensorflow uses Eigen to optimise CPU operations. So will I need to write a custom op using Eigen etc. to make fourier_conv2d compare to/faster than conv2d?