# Why does runtime not scale with flops - Pointwise Multiplication vs 2D Convolutions

Tags: python, pytorch

## **Background**

Based on the convolution theorem of Fourier Transforms convolutions in the spatial domain are equivalent to pointwise multiplications in the Fourier domain (and the other way around). I implemented a `torch.nn.Conv2d` that "operates" in the Fourier domain by performing pointwise multiplication instead of convolution (with a kernel that is transformed to the size of the intput) in PyTorch (as described e.g. here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5851.pdf)

## **Expectation & Results**

I found that it did not perform well, similar to: [Keras/Tensorflow - fourier pointwise multiplication implementation of conv2d running 4x slower than spatial convolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55453119/keras-tensorflow-fourier-pointwise-multiplication-implementation-of-conv2d-run)

After a number of benchmarks it appears that the pointwise multiplication is the major bottleneck of the operation. During the benchmarks I excluded the FFT process to isolate the operations of the layer (and used saved kernels in the appropriate size).

This is confusing because when considering the number of FLOPs required for a 2D convolution (stride=1) and element-wise multiplication:

- Conv2d FLOPs: `Kernel_H * Kernel_W * C_in * C_out * H * W`
- Pointwise FLOPs: `C_in * C_out * H * W`

E.g. given `H = 32, W = 60, C_in = 64, C_out = 256`:

- Conv2d FLOPs (k = 16): `16 * 16 * 32 * 60 * 64 * 256 = 8053 MFLOPs`
- Pointwise (FLOPs): `64 * 256 * 32 * 60 = 31.46 MFLOPs`

Considering that large difference in FLOPs I would expect the 2D convolution to take much longer to run (have read GPUs are optimized well for dot products)

I created a simple script to benchmark pointwise multiplication of `torch.Tensor` against `torch.nn.Conv2d`, since it appeared that the performance was equivalent or even slower for elementwise multiplication compared to 2D convolutions.

Below is an overview of 2 such benchmark result on a CPU and GPU (i9900k with `torch.set_num_threads(1)`)

**Results - CPU (i9900k)**

```
(# Kernel Size = 16)

Benchmark Overview (device = cpu):
    Number of test iterations: 100
    Number of warm-up iterations: 5
    Pointwise: [1, 256, 32, 60] * [64, 256, 32, 60]
    Conv2d(in_ch=256, out_ch=64, kernel_size=16): Conv2d([1, 256, 32, 60)
    FLOP Estimation:
        Conv2d:      8053.06368 MFlops
        Pointwise:   31.45728 MFlops


Benchmark Results (device = cpu)
    Pointwise:   16.139 +/- 0.786 ms
    Conv2d:      12.947 +/- 0.784 ms

-------------------------
(# Kernel Size = 5)

Benchmark Overview (device = cpu):
    Number of test iterations: 100
    Number of warm-up iterations: 5
    Pointwise: [1, 256, 32, 60] * [64, 256, 32, 60]
    Conv2d(in_ch=256, out_ch=64, kernel_size=5): Conv2d([1, 256, 32, 60)
    FLOP Estimation:
        Conv2d:      786.432 MFlops
        Pointwise:   31.45728 MFlops

Benchmark Results (device = cpu)
    Pointwise:   36.085 +/- 3.668 ms
    Conv2d:      9.344 +/- 0.952 ms
```

**Results - GPU (RTX Titan)**

```
(# Kernel Size = 16)

Benchmark Overview (device = cuda:1):
    Number of test iterations: 1000
    Number of warm-up iterations: 5
    Pointwise: [1, 256, 32, 60] * [64, 256, 32, 60]
    Conv2d(in_ch=256, out_ch=64, kernel_size=16): Conv2d([1, 256, 32, 60)
    FLOP Estimation:
        Conv2d:      8053.06368 MFlops
        Pointwise:   31.45728 MFlops

Benchmark Results (device = cuda:1)
    Pointwise:   0.698 +/- 0.031 ms
    Conv2d:      2.916 +/- 0.161 ms

------------------------------------

(# Kernel size = 3)

Benchmark Overview (device = cuda:1):
    Number of test iterations: 100
    Number of warm-up iterations: 5
    Pointwise: [1, 256, 32, 60] * [64, 256, 32, 60]
    Conv2d(in_ch=256, out_ch=64, kernel_size=3): Conv2d([1, 256, 32, 60)
    FLOP Estimation:
        Conv2d:      283.11552 MFlops
        Pointwise:   31.45728 MFlops
        FreqConv:    62.91456 MFlops

Benchmark Results (device = cuda:1)
    Pointwise:   0.681 +/- 0.011 ms
    Conv2d:      0.126 +/- 0.034 ms
```

The results do not appear to change significantly if I change the `H` or `W` or the channels. But for smaller kernels pointwise appears significantly slower.

## **Question**

Can anyone suggest why the pointwise multiplication appears to be so slow when the FLOPs are at least 2 orders of magnitude larger, or where there may be an error in my thinking or code?

**Benchmark Implementation**

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch import nn
from time import time

torch.set_num_threads(1)

in_ch = 256
out_ch = 64
height = 32
width = 60
kernel_size = 16

warmup = 5
iters = 100

flops_pointwise = (out_ch * in_ch * height * width)
m_flops_conv = (flops_pointwise * kernel_size ** 2) / 1e6
m_flops_pw = (flops_pointwise) / 1e6

# Device to run benchmark on, e.g. 'cpu' or 'cuda:X'
device = 'cpu'

print(f'Benchmark Overview (device = {device}):')
print(f'\tNumber of test iterations: {iters}')
print(f'\tNumber of warm-up iterations: {warmup}')
print(f'\tPointwise: [1, {in_ch}, {height}, {width}] * [{out_ch}, {in_ch}, {height}, {width}]') 
print(f'\tConv2d(in_ch={in_ch}, out_ch={out_ch}, kernel_size={kernel_size}): Conv2d([1, {in_ch}, {height}, {width})')

print('\tFLOP Estimation:')
print(f'\t\tConv2d:\t\t {m_flops_conv} MFlops')
print(f'\t\tPointwise:\t {m_flops_pw} MFlops')
print(f'\t\tFreqConv:\t {m_flops_freq_conv} MFlops')

print()

def benchmark(input_gen, operation, warmup=5, iters=1000):
    duration = []
    for i in range(iters + warmup):

        input = input_gen()

        start = time() # start timer
        with torch.no_grad():
            operation(input)

        # Sync if using cuda
        if device[:4] == 'cuda':
            torch.cuda.synchronize(device)
        end = time() # end timer

        if i < warmup:
            continue

        duration.append((end - start) * 1e3) # ms

    return np.array(duration)


def pointwise(input):
    x, y = input
    x * y

# Helper methods to generate new data
# for every iteration inside of the benchmark method

def _gen_pw_input(in_ch, out_ch, height, width):
    x = torch.rand(1, in_ch, height, width).to(device)
    k = torch.randn(out_ch, in_ch, height, width).to(device)
    return x, k

gen_pw_input = lambda : _gen_pw_input(in_ch, out_ch, height, width)

def _gen_conv_input(in_ch, out_ch, height, width):
    x = torch.rand(1, in_ch, height, width).to(device)
    return x

gen_conv_input = lambda : _gen_conv_input(in_ch, out_ch, height, width)



conv2d = nn.Conv2d(in_ch, out_ch, kernel_size=kernel_size).to(device)

pw_res = benchmark(gen_pw_input, pointwise, warmup=warmup, iters=iters)
conv_res = benchmark(gen_conv_input, conv2d, warmup=warmup, iters=iters)

print(f'Benchmark Results (device = {device})')
print('\tPointwise:\t {:.3f} +/- {:.3f} ms'.format(pw_res.mean(), pw_res.std()))
print('\tConv2d:\t\t {:.3f} +/- {:.3f} ms'.format(conv_res.mean(), conv_res.std()))
```

**Eigen**

I also implemented a basic benchmark test in Eigen (C++) to compare the elementwise multiplication and it was similar (slightly slower) to results observed in PyTorch; the backend BLAS used by PyTorch appears optimized.